# Angular 2 - Refresh ngx-datatable list issue

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngx-datatable

I'm working on an Angular 2 project.
I use ngx-datatable to display a list of users:

```
<ngx-datatable class="material"
[rows]="rows"
[columnMode]="'force'"
[headerHeight]="40"
[footerHeight]="40"
[rowHeight]="30"
[externalPaging]="true"
[limit]="limit"
(select)='onSelect($event)'
(activate)='onActivate($event)'
[selected]="selected"
[selectionType]="'checkbox'">
<ngx-datatable-column
    [width]="30"
    [sortable]="false"
    [canAutoResize]="false"
    [draggable]="false"
    [resizeable]="false"
    [headerCheckboxable]="true"
    [checkboxable]="true">
  </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Name">
        <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            <div class="redNumber">{{value}}</div>
        </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
  <ngx-datatable-column name="Title"></ngx-datatable-column>
  <ngx-datatable-column name="company"></ngx-datatable-column>
  <ngx-datatable-column name="Status" [cellClass]="getStatusClass">  
  </ngx-datatable-column>
<ngx-datatable-column name="Last connexion"></ngx-datatable-column>
```

When I click on the button that trigger the following showAll() method, nothing happens, unless I click a second time, the list is refreshed, or if I click once, and resize my browser's window, the list is refreshed..
How can I refresh the list correctly? what am I doing wrong?
In my component class, I have this:

```
export class M1OamRoomsListComponent{ 
    selected = [];
    public rows = [
      .... // list of users
    ];
public limit: number;

constructor(public translation: TranslationService){
    this.limit = 10;
}

getStatusClass({ row, column, value }): any {
    return {
        'disabled': value === 'Disabled',
        'enabled': value === 'Enabled'
    };
}
onSelect({ selected }) {
    console.log('Select Event', selected, this.selected);

    this.selected.splice(0, this.selected.length);
    this.selected.push(...selected);
}

onActivate(event) {
    //console.log('Activate Event', event);
}
showAll(): void {
    this.limit = this.rows.length;
}
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think to refresh the table you must do:

```
this.rows = [...this.rows]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: love u broi! u saved me.

Comment: It looks they used angular `changeDetection:onPush` strategy for the grid to optimize performace. #of items are in the paging area were increasing, but rows were not getting updated.

Comment: Yeah, as I guessed https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/cd

Answer (score 3):

```
this.rows.push(result);
this.rows = [...this.rows]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to swimlane page of `ngx-datatable`, `ngx-datatable` follow OnPush change detection strategy, hence it only checks for immutable data types.
So if you want `ngx-datatable` to detect changes. After doing :

```
  this.selected.push(...selected);
```

Do:

```
this.selected = [...this.selected]
```

Read more about change detection here: [Link](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled with this post because I was having a problem when any column was being sorted the UI was not updating a inner component until I scroll up and down again.

I managed to do a workaround with what was suggested previously:

UI:

```
<ngx-datatable (......) (sort)="onSort()">
```

TS:

```
  onSort() {
    const data = this.filteredTableValues;
    this.filteredTableValues = [];
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.filteredTableValues = [...data];
  }
```

Hope this helps someone in the same case